# Why does the main thread wait the thread created by std::async() if the return value is not hold by lvalue?

Tags: c++, multithreading, asynchronous, future

When I run the following code,

```cpp
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <future>

int main() {
    auto fut = std::async(
        std::launch::async, 
        []{
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
            std::cout << "sub : " << std::this_thread::get_id() << std::endl;
        }
    ); 

    std::cout << "do some on main thread" << std::endl;
    
    fut.get();

    std::cout << "main: " << std::this_thread::get_id() << std::endl;
}
```

I got the following output.

```
do some on main thread
sub : 139899103246080
main: 139899103250240
```

Running demo: https://godbolt.org/z/c9WedY4oq

It is the same behavior as I expected.
"do some on main thread" outputs first, because the sub thread created by `std::async()` waits 1 second the beggining of the thread.

So far, so good.

---

However, when I removed the variable `fut`, then I got weird behavior for me.
NOTE: This code is for only experimental purpose

```cpp
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <future>

int main() {
    std::async(
        std::launch::async, 
        []{
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
            std::cout << "sub : " << std::this_thread::get_id() << std::endl;
        }
    ); 

    std::cout << "do some on main thread" << std::endl;
    
    std::cout << "main: " << std::this_thread::get_id() << std::endl;
}
```

Here is the output:

```
sub : 139716056966912
do some on main thread
main: 139716056971072
```

Running demo: https://godbolt.org/z/obzzceGGr

It seems that the main thread waits until finishing the sub thread before outputing "do some on main thread".

I want to know why this behavior happens.

I got the warning message ":6:5: warning: ignoring return value of function declared with 'nodiscard' attribute [-Wunused-result]".
Since C++20, the nodiscard attribute has been added.
See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async

I guess that I got an undefined behavior due to ignoring the return value of `std::async()`, but I couldn't find such document, so far.

Comment: On another note, using `std::async` for doing an operation which doesn't return anything is rather useless. For that use plain `std::thread` (or [`std::jthread`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/jthread)).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the second case, a `std::future` object will still be created and returned.

That object is ephemeral and will be destructed immediately, and that leads to your problem because [the `std::future` *destructor*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future/%7Efuture) will wait for the future to be ready before destruction continues.

Comment: Thans you! I clrearly understand. I wrote another PoC code https://godbolt.org/z/j8b4aY9j9 and confirm the behavior.